# Cloning a class and appending the second value in the cloned class

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax for retrieving names from the database, when the names are more than one, i split them then clone the first class so that i can have the other name(second) in the cloned class. It seems not to work, What am i missing?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: base_url + "c_transfer/viewTransfer/" + transfer_id,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        var all_transferors = data[0]['Transferor_Name'];
        var sole_transferors = all_transferors.split(',');
        for (transferor_counter = 0; transferor_counter < sole_transferors.length; transferor_counter++) {
            if (transferor_counter > 0) {
                $('.clone').relCopy({});
                $("#transferor_name").val(sole_transferors[transferor_counter]);
            } else {
                $("#transferor_name").val(sole_transferors[transferor_counter]);
                console.log(sole_transferors[transferor_counter]);
            }
            // console.log(sole_transferors[transferor_counter]);
        }
```

Comment: TL;DR. Don't post code this way.

Comment: Not sure about the use of `relCopy()` here.  You'd be better using `clone()` to create the copy and `append()` to add it to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

#### Are you trying to do this?

```
$("#transferor_name").val(sole_transferors[transferor_counter].val());
```

You need to use `.val()` at the end?

Comment: `sole_transferors` is a string array

Comment: Yes its a string array, it works for the first class only but now i need to clone the same $("#transferor_name") to append the second array value